# Automatic Hudson CI setup and plugin updates through apt?

Tags: java, continuous-integration, debian, hudson-plugins

We've used [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) for quite a while to implement a CI server with all the bells and whistles. The setup is quite straight forward, when installing from the provided RPMs and Debs, but through googling I haven't been able to figure out whether the plugins are installable using apt/rpm or some other package manager?

The reason is that I would like to create a (meta)package for Ubuntu which would install and also update both Hudson and all the plugins through the normal upgrade mechanism. At the same time I could create a template setup for other projects, say JavaEE project needs git, cobertura and Chuck Norris plugins, while my Python project needs plugins XXX and YYY.

Anybody got such a setup? As a workaround I figured setting up a number of Maven POMs, which would do the init, and later upgrades, but I feel this would require more scripting on the side, which I'm not very eager to do.

Any other suggestions for this would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I haven't been able to figure out whether the plugins are installable using apt/rpm or some other package manager?

They are installed "manually".

> The reason is that I would like to create a (meta)package for Ubuntu which would install and also update both Hudson and all the plugins through the normal upgrade mechanism. (...)

I'm not aware of an existing solution for this (very likely because packaging plugins is a big mistake *in general*: it's a lot of work for the linux distros and plugins go much faster than the release cycles). So I guess you'll have to package them yourself.

And be careful with upgrades of Hudson, they often break plugins (in other words, I recommend to test the upgrade of Hudson in a test environment, like a virtual machine).

> Anybody got such a setup? (...)

I bundle plugins in an archive and unzip them in `<HUDSON_HOME>/plugins/`.

Comment: I do agree, that there is no need to add the plugins in the distro repos. However, Hudson installation from http://hudson-ci.org/debian/ is in my opinion a better way to keep the installation up-to-date, than using the UI for this. I think that the since the actual server, with some plugins bundled in, is published as .deb anyway. I don't feel that providing the plugins in the same manner would be a very bad thing either. Especially considering that the plugins are versioned anyway, and installed automatically by the Hudson UI.

Comment: @aapeli My point is that plugins and hudson have different lifecycle and that **qualifying** and packaging all plugins for a given hudson version is a huge work and that there is no reason for the maintainers of http://hudson-ci.org/debian/ to do it, that would be insane. However, feel free to do it yourself for **your** plugins.